# Laravel 5 laracasts flash messaging not showing error div

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, flash-message

I've been trying to get a flash message letting the user know that their message from the contact form has successfully been sent, I found [This Github Repo](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) in which there's an "easy" way of flashing error messages in Laravel 5 (I'm using Laravel 5.2) so I went on an tried using it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The classes are all being found, the problem here is that it won't flash after I redirect.

In my `master.blade.php`

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))
<div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

    {{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}
</div>
@endif
```

In my `routes.php`

```
Route::post('sendemail', function () {

    $data = array(
        'name' => "Learning Laravel",
    );

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {

        $message->from('email@provider', 'Learning Laravel!');

        $message->to('email@provider')->subject('Learning Laravel test email');

    });
        Flash::message('Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible.');

        return Redirect::to('/');

});
```

What am I doing wrong / forgetting?

**EDIT** Complete `routes.php`

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::post('sendemail', function () {

    $data = array(
        'name' => "Learning Laravel",
    );

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {

        $message->from('email@provider', 'Learning Laravel!');

        $message->to('email@provider')->subject('Learning Laravel test email');

    });
        Session::put('flash_notification.message', 'Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible.');

        return Redirect::to('/');

});
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the flash:message to Session::put and make sure they are under "web" middleware group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    });

    Route::post('sendemail', function () {

        $data = array(
           'name' => "Learning Laravel",
        );

        Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {

           $message->from('email@provider', 'Learning Laravel!');

           $message->to('email@provider')->subject('Learning Laravel test email');

       });
           Session::put('flash_notification.message', 'Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you as soon as possible.');

           return Redirect::to('/');

    });


});
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work, It still doesn't show the `<div>`

Comment: if your home route under web middleware? or any middleware that keeps the sessions?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, this is a clean install of Laravel 5

Comment: Hmm how about 'sendemail' route? In order for the sessions to work they need to be placed in web middleware.

Comment: I'm rather new to laravel so I basically don't know how to get the form to submit to a middleware.

Comment: No worries. Can you post your full routes.php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105054/discussion-between-can-celik-and-simplicity).